# How to get the On/Off toggle button value using jQuery?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

One of my test scenarios has an On-Off toggle button and I want to check is it on or off?
The button value has an internal checkbox so I used a JQuery to get the checkbox value but I am getting a `null` value.

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
System.out.println(js.executeScript("$('#f-contact-usactive').is(':checked')"));
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="label">Display Contact Us
       <i title="If this field is left blank, it will revert to 
                 the default Teleflora/group value." 
          class="icon icon-tool-tip icon-tool-tip-federated">
       </i>
       <i title="This controls whether or not your address and 
                 phone number will show on the about us page." 
          class="icon icon-tool-tip x-space-s">
       </i>
    </div>
    <input checked="" type="checkbox" id="f-contact-us-active" 
           name="f-contact-us-active" class="on-off-switch">
    <label for="f-contact-us-active" class="on-off-switch-label">
        <div class="on-off-switch-state">on</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Please help me to get the value

Comment: There is a typo in your jQuery selector ; `#f-contact-usactive` in your JS script, `id="f-contact-us-active"` in your HTML.

Comment: <input checked="" type="checkbox" id="f-contact-us-active" name="f-contact-us-active" class="on-off-switch"> <label for="f-contact-us-active" class="on-off-switch-label"> is the check box value

Comment: and when i tried to get the checkbox value using the $('#f-contact-us-active').is(':checked') or "$('#f-contact-us-active').is(':checked')" in browser console i can see the value as True if it's on and false for off

Comment: yes I have updated but still i am not getiing the value

Comment: Is jQuery loaded in your selenium context?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172217/discussion-between-user3538483-and-rogerc).

Answer (score 0):

your id is not correct in JQuery selector. it should be something like this. `"$('#f-contact-us-active').is(':checked')"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your id for the checkbox is "f-contact-us-active" but in the script you are accessing "f-contact-usactive" missing a '-'.

Or have you done the typo here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs and I got the solution

System.out.println("The Toggle value is: "+((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return document.getElementById('f-contact-us-active').checked"));